# What exactly is "data" that is passed to responses?

Tags: sails.js

I'm writing a custom response that takes `data` as an input, and I am finding strange properties being added, namely:

```
add: [Function: add],
remove: [Function: remove]
```

When I log out some example `data`, I get:

```
[ { books: 
     [ { id: 1,
         title: 'A Game of Thrones',
         createdAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.043Z',
         updatedAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.080Z',
         author: 1 } ],
    id: 1,
    name: 'George R. R. Martin',
    createdAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.040Z',
    updatedAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.073Z' },
  { books: 
     [ { id: 2,
         title: 'Ender\'s Game',
         createdAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.043Z',
         updatedAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.080Z',
         author: 2 },
       { id: 3,
         title: 'Speaker for the Dead',
         createdAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.043Z',
         updatedAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.081Z',
         author: 2 } ],
    id: 2,
    name: 'Orson Scott Card',
    createdAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.042Z',
    updatedAt: '2015-08-04T04:53:38.074Z' } ]
```

Which looks innocent enough, but results in the strange `add` and `remove` functions when I use a custom serializer on it.  If I take this data and hard-code it straight into the serializer, those are not present.  Apparently something is lurking inside of `data` that's not being printed to the console.

So, what is `data`?

Edit: So, I'm still not quite sure what other magical properties live in here, but:

```
Object.keys(data[0].books))
```

reveals

```
[ '0', 'add', 'remove' ]
```

Which is where those are coming from.  Why is this included in the data passed to custom responses?  And what else might be hiding in there...

More importantly, how do I strip this gunk out and make `data` a normal object?

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

That cleans it up nicely, though it feels like a hack.  (Actually, it's definitely a hack.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `data` attribute is returned by a database query. e.g.:

```
Model.find(...).exec(function (err, data) { ... });
```

But what are these `.add()` and `.remove()` methods?

Here is what you can find [in the docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records):

> For the most part, records are just plain old JavaScript objects (aka POJOs). However they do have a few protected (non-enumerable) methods for formatting their wrapped data, as well as a special method (`.save()`) for persisting programmatic changes to the database.

We can [go deeper](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values):

> "collection" associations, on the other hand, do have a couple of special (non-enumerable) methods for associating and disassociating linked records. However, `.save()` must still be called on the original record in order for changes to be persisted to the database.
>
> ```
> orders[1].buyers.add({ name: 'Jon Snow' });
> orders[1].save(function (err) { ... });
> ```

So these methods (`.add()`, `.remove()`, `.save()`) are useful if you play with "collection" associations.

How to remove them?

You'll need to use [`.toObject()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-object) which returns a cloned model instance stripped of all instance methods.

You might want to use [`.toJSON()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json) that also returns a cloned model instance. This one however includes all instance methods.

Comment: I am not explicitly calling `Model.find()`, and I'm not sure how `data` is constructed.  It's not fully a waterline object, as `.toObject()` and `.toJSON()` are undefined on it.  It is passed into the response function as in: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/responses/defaults/ok.js#L14

Comment: It has to be the first param you give to `res.custom()` when you call it (it's not constructed anywhere). Are you using the blueprints actions?

Comment: I've not done anything with blueprints.  This is a hook which should be installable into any sails app.  I've just released it at: https://github.com/IanVS/sails-hook-jsonapi